# Can Chinese users who read the app store in traditional see a simplified description?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect, chinese-locale

Can Chinese users who read the app store in traditional Chinese see a simplified Chinese description?  My app is currently only translated to simplified, and I only specified the simplified translation in iTunes connect.  I wonder if I'm losing traditional Chinese readers or if the app store simply reverts to Simplified for them?  How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People for Hong Kong or Macau may have difficulties reading Simplified Chinese, since their native locale is the traditional one.

Try having 2 versions of Chinese, or use Google if needed.

http://translate.google.com/?tl=zh-TW#zh-CN/zh-TW/%E9%BE%99